# Мнемонические правила русского языка

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, правила, обучение

Я знаю, что есть некоторые стихи для заучивания разных правил русского языка.
Например, про падежи:

> **И**ван (именительный) **Р**одил (родительный) **Д**евчонку (дательный),
>
> **В**елел (винительный) **Т**ащить (творительный) **П**еленку (предложный).

Или (*одевать/надевать*):

> Мы пошли с Надюшей в душ,
>
> Вдруг приперся Надин муж.
>
> То ли мне надеть одежду?
>
> То ли мне одеть Надежду?

Или:

> Цыган на цыпочках цыпленку цыкнул "цыц".

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своими вариантами заучивания (мнемоники).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1**. Для запоминания падежей русского языка:

**И**ван **Р**убил **Д**рова, **В**арвара **Т**опила **П**ечь.

**И**мя **Р**одители **Д**али, **В**инни **Т**оптыжкой **П**розвали.

**И**ван
**Р**одионович,
**Д**айте
**В**ашу
**Т**рубку
**П**окурить!

Есть стишок и на обратный порядок падежей:
**П**еленку
**Т**ащит
**В**еликан:
"**Д**авай
**Р**ожай,
**И**ван!"

**2**. **Уж замуж невтерпеж** — мнемофраза для запоминания слов без **ь** в наречиях на шипящий.

**3**. Мнеморифмовки при запоминании существительных в родительном падеже множественного числа:

Уважают человека у туркмен, татар, узбеков,
У таджиков и армян, у монголов и цыган,
У якутов и тунгусов, у башкир и белорусов,
У киргизов и грузин, у бурят и осетин.

В детской сказке колобок по траве катиться мог
***Без ботинок, без сапог, без носков и без чулок.***

Шесть гектаров ***апельсинов, яблок, груш и мандаринов,***
***Баклажанов*** – грядок пять, ***помидоров*** –  не собрать.

**4**. Рифмовка для запоминания корней ***– зар-, -зор-:***

*Заря, зарница, озаренный, озарять –*
По слову *зарево* я буду проверять.

**5**.  Пять слов, где не пишется "т" между С и Н:

***Не чудесно, не прекрасно, а ужасно и опасно букву Т писать напрасно!***

**6**. Для запоминания написания *не кто иной, как…, не что иное, как…*

НЕ раздельно пишет всяк,
Если дальше – слово *как.*

**7**. Правило: в суффиксах *-АН-/-ЯН-* прилагательных пишется одна буква *Н*, слова-исключения: оловяННый, деревяННый, стекляННый.

В окне СТЕКЛЯННОЕ стекло, ДЕРЕВЯННАЯ рама и ОЛОВЯННЫЕ ручки.

Посмотрите на окно:
В окне стеклянное стекло,
Рамы деревянные,
Ручки оловянные.

**8**. Глаголы c **-ся**:

Кто в глаголах пишет **ЦА**, —
Настоящая овца.

**9**. Дефис в неопределенных местоимениях:

***То, кое, либо, нибудь -***
черточку не забудь.
А частицы ***же, бы, ли***
Ты раздельно запиши.

**10**. Орфоэпические стишки (здесь примеров - великое множество!):

ФенОмен звонИт по средАм,
ПринЯв договОр по годАм,
Он Отдал экспЕртам эскОрта
ХодАтайство аэропОрта.

ЗвонИт звонарь,
ЗвонЯт в звонок,
Чтоб ты запомнить верно смог.
ЗвонИт и говорИт.

**11**. Глаголы - исключения (тут вариантов тоже много):

Ко второму же спряженью
Отнесем мы без сомненья
Все глаголы, что на **-ить,**
Исключая **брить, стелить.**

А еще: *смотреть, обидеть,

слышать, видеть, ненавидеть,

гнать, дышать, держать, терпеть,

И зависеть, и вертеть.*
Вы запомните, друзья,
*Их на Е спрягать нельзя.*

**12**. Мнемоника для определения обстоятельств:

Семь вопросов – просто чудо,
Их запомнить просто так:
***Где? куда? когда? откуда?

Почему? зачем? и как?***

**13**. "О" после шипящих:

Шоколад,шоссе, крыжовник,
шов, шофер, обжора, шорник,
капюшон, жокей, чащоба,
шорох, чопорный, трущоба.

Можно найти в интернете [**"Веселые запоминалки"**](https://inteltoys.ru/articles/cat2/article475.html), или "Запоминалки - Правила русского языка в рифмах", или [**"Лучшие запоминалки"**](https://vk.com/zapominashki).

**14**. Слова, не упо­треб­ля­ю­щи­е­ся без **не-** (дополнение):

Побывал я однажды в стране,
Где исчезла частица **НЕ**.
Посмотрел я вокруг с **доуменьем**,
Что за **лепое** положение?
Но кругом было тихо-тихо,
И во всём была **разбериха**,
А на **взрачной** клумбе у будки
Голубые цвели **забудки**.

И погода стояла **настная**,
И гуляла собака **счастная**.
И, виляя хвостом **уклюже**,
Пробегала **пролазную** лужу.
Мне навстречу без всякого страха
Шёл умытый причёсанный **ряха**,
А за **ряхой** по травке свежей
Шёл **суразный дотёпа** и **вежа**.

А из школы, взявшись за ручки,
Чинным шагом вышли **доучки**.
И навстречу всем утром рано
Улыбалась царевна **Смеяна**.
Очень жаль, что только во сне
Есть страна без частицы **НЕ**.

Comment: Ух ты!!!  Зыко!!!

Comment: Спасибо, Саша. Как вспомню, сколько времени угрохала на этот ответ (я тогда только осваивалась на сайте), — так вздрогну.

Answer (score 2):

Иван рубил дрова, Варвара топила печь. Имя Родители Дали, Винни Топтыжкой Прозвали — **для запоминания падежей русского языка.**

Уж замуж невтерпеж — **мнемофраза для запоминания слов без ь в наречиях на шипящий**.

Орфоэпические стишки:

Долго ели тОрты —
Не налезли шОрты.

Как у нашей Марфы
Есть в полоску шАрфы!

---

Срубили ель,
сорвали щавЕль.

---

В огороде баба Фёкла,
у нее на грядке свЁкла!

---

ЗвонИт звонарь,
ЗвонЯт в звонок,
Чтоб ты запомнить верно смог.