# Надеть или одеть

Tags: грамотная-речь

Ребенок плачет, когда надеваю ему шапку, от надевания куртки тоже плачет. Правильно ли ?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433277/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Этот вопрос имел приемлемый ответ. Пользуйтесь  П о и с к о м.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грамматически правильно ("одеваю" или "надеваю" - все равно), стилистически - нет.

Правильно:

> Ребенок плачет, когда надеваю ему шапку или куртку.