# «Одевать» или «надевать»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы

Правильно ли употребляется «одевай» на данном плакате:
[image: "Работая вибратором одевай резиновые сапоги и перчатки"]
[image: Плакат]
«Работая вибратором одевай резиновые сапоги и перчатки».

Ведь в данном случае надевать призывают на себя, а не одевать кого-то.
Не правильнее было бы употребление **«надевай»**?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Мнемонические правила русского языка](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433277/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Работая вибратором, надевай резиновые сапоги и перчатки.***

Конечно, правильно в данном случае использовать глагол ***надевать***. Ещё на плакате допущена грамматическая ошибка: нет запятой, отделяющей деепричастный оборот.

Информацию можно получить из многочисленных источников, например [**здесь**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?id=36_119&layout=item) (Грамота.ру).

P. S. Возможно, в необозримом будущем, глаголы «одеть/одевать», «надеть/надевать» войдут в толковые словари как равноправные, так как уж больно часто носители языка используют одно вместо другого. Может, и «зв**ó**нит» вместо «звон**и́**т» тоже станет нормативным, ведь «к**á**тит», например, давно заменил «кат**и́**т».

Comment: "Зв**о**нит" совершенно точно станет нормой, как стали "к**у**рит", "в**а**рит" и ещё целый ряд подобных глаголов (когда-то говорили "кур**и**т", "вар**и**т"). // Насчёт одевать = надевать... Когда-то был, насколько я знаю, глагол "набуть". Потом отмер, и остался только глагол "обуть". Но тем не менее он не стал синонимом "набуть", то есть до сих пор считается просторечием выражение "обул ботинки", а литературная норма только "обул ноги в ботинки". Так что по идее синонимами одевать-надевать не должны бы стать.

Answer (score 3):

1. Итак, **оригинальный плакат из 30-х годов.** Общего свода правил пока еще нет, да и грамматические требования еще не настолько строгие, вот и пишут "одевай сапоги  и перчатки".

**"Грамматическая война"** между "одень" и "надень" начнется позже или уже началась?

2. А это "**Слово устное и слово письменное**. Беседные очерки" Б. Шергина (1893–1973). Дневниковые записи относятся к периоду 1938 – 1968 годов.

«Русский язык стал языком литературы. Что же, река живой народной речи и река русской речи литературной слились воедино? Нет, они остались неслиянны, хотя и нераздельны. Это потому, что у писателя (классика) все сковано единой идеей: и фундамент, и стены, и кровля – все сцементировано единой мыслью… К творению писателя-классика ничего не прибавишь, не убавишь.

Но рядом, но вокруг неутомленно бегущая, **терпкая разговорная речь**. Сколько струй чистых и мутных, светло-прозрачных и иловатых! В последнее время и в печати не раз поднимался вопрос **о чистоте литературного языка.**

Порою также делаются ребятам краткие, но убедительные внушения: – **Нельзя говорить:** одел калоши, раздел пальто. Калоши надо надеть; раздеть можно человека, пальто надо снять. **Правильному языку учитесь у великих наших классиков.**

3. Но вернемся **в XIX век или в начало XX века**, когда работали наши великие классики или просто известные литераторы. И вот как-то незаметно, чтобы они **строго придерживались одной формы.** Эта тема не раз уже поднималась и обсуждалась на форуме.

Переобулся Иван Леонтьич из валенков в сапоги, **одел сюртук** и сел к самовару,  [Н. С. Лесков. Грабеж (1887)]

Офицер окинул его с ног до головы несколько удивленным взглядом, улыбнулся слегка, пожал плечами и беспрекословно **помог одеть пальто.** [Ф. М. Достоевский. Дневник писателя (1877)]

Встал, повязал на воротник мягкой сорочки галстук, взял трость, одел шляпу и пошёл. [В. В. Брусянин. Опустошённые души (1915)]

Я говорю: извини, Лорд, одел тут кое-что из твоего, пока тебя не было. [Мариам Петросян. Дом, в котором... (2009)]

4. Но, может быть, это вовсе не писатели, а наши **лингвисты** обозначили **непримиримое противостояние** между этими словами? В любом случае мы «одеваем»  себя или кого-то одеждой или обувью. Нюансы, конечно, есть, но иногда они кажутся формальностью.
5. И вот русский разговорный язык **упорно сопротивляется** формальному грамматическому давлению, хотя в качестве примеров для подражания нам приводят цитаты из классиков. Мне же кажется, что классики вполне терпимо относились к обеим формам. Возможно, в будущем мы также придем к такому решению.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134764/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---).

Comment: Интересная статься по теме: https://ollimpia.ru/kogda-stali-govorit-nadevat/   "Но среди лингвистов есть те, кто не разделяет такой суровый подход и считает, что норму стоит смягчить. Слишком уж часто в речевой практике разных людей глагол одеть употребляется вместо надеть: одеть шапку, одеть платье… В список попали А. Чехов, Н. Лесков, Ф. Достоевский, М. Горький, Б. Пастернак, Б. Окуджава и другие…"